# Don't Render HTML + TypeScript into Meteor Template

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular

I'm using Meteor + Angular2 + Typescript + FlowRouter + FlowLayout. After successful login, it renders home page, but does not render `parties-list.ng.html`. If I refresh again, it works.

index.html

```html
<body>
    {{> main }}
</body>
<template name="main">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</template>
<template name="home">
    <nav>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </nav>
    <parties-list></parties-list>
    <script>System.import('client/parties-list');</script>
</template>
```

router.js

```js
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    action: function() {
        Tracker.autorun(function() {
            if (!Meteor.userId()) {
                FlowRouter.go('/login');
            } else {
                FlowLayout.render('main', { main: 'home' });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

parties-list.ts

```ts
import {Component, View, bootstrap, For, If} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'parties-list'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'client/parties-list.ng.html',
    directives: [For, If]
})
class PartiesList {
    constructor() {}
}
bootstrap(PartiesList);
```

Comment: This issue may be related to browser caching. If you're using Chrome, try going to devTools -> settings -> disable cache (while dev tools is open).

Comment: I tried, but don't working

Comment: Have you tried moving your system.import statement inside of the body, rather than inside a template?

Comment: Yes, i tried. Don't woking too

Comment: Syntax hilighting wasn't working; grammar and title.